# Cannot coerce class structure("BinaryTree", package = "party") to a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, weka, ctree

I have a conditional inference tree model (`ctree`) saved in an R `.rda` file and am trying to convert it into a Weka `.arff` file:

```
library("foreign")

load("my_ctree.rda")
write.arff(my_ctree, file = "outputFile.arff")
```

but I get error:

> Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) :    cannot
>   coerce class ‘structure("BinaryTree", package = "party")’ to a
>   data.frame

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using the partykit package?  (I'm guessing.)  If so, the result of the ctree function is a party object which is itself not a data.frame but a more complex data structure.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the `party` package. Does it mean there is not a function already available to perform this conversion?

Comment: Do you know what a binary tree is?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but the .arff file is a data file format for Weka and ctree is a structure that results from trading a binary tree ground the party package.  Are you trying to import the binary tree into Weka?  I don't know if that's possible.

Comment: trading should be training

Comment: Yes, I’m trying to import the binary tree trained from the the R party package into the Java Weka library.

Comment: As @KirkD-CO says the [ARFF format](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/arff_stable/) is for datasets, not models. What do you want to do with the tree in Weka - evaluate its performance using Weka? use it to make predictions on a new dataset? Maybe you want to use [RPlugin](http://weka.sourceforge.net/packageMetaData/RPlugin/index.html)?